# When did Isaac Barrow solve the integral of $\sec {x}$?

Tags: math-history, trigonometric-integrals

I hope this is the correct site to ask "When did Isaac Barrow solve the integral of $\sec{x}$". I have searched on the internet and he is often credited with this, but no one gives the date he did it. I would like to know to be able to refer to this in a talk on Mercator's Map Projection.

Comment: see this here http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2009-03/msg00167.html

Comment: See I.Barrow, [Geometrical Lectures](https://books.google.it/books?id=dfA2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA256) (1670), **Lecture XII, Appendix III**. Comments into :  [Child's edition](https://archive.org/stream/geometricallectu00barruoft#page/182/mode/2up) (1916), page 183 and Enrique González-Velasco, [Journey through Mathematics : Creative Episodes in Its History](https://books.google.it/books?id=0sTd4qJgOmsC&pg=PA287) (2011), page 287.